# Finding n points that are equidistant around the circumference of an ellipse

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Hello all.  This is probably a simple problem for you guys, but my geometry is a bit rusty and I am hoping that you can help.

I am trying to arrange an arbitrary number of objects around the circumference of an ellipse.  My first stab at the problem resulted in the use of a simple rotational matrix like this (note that I am using graphical Cartesian coordinates where y increases down from the top of the screen).

```
def rotate(x, y, theta)
  x_p = (x * Math.cos(theta)) - (y * Math.sin(theta))
  y_p = (y * Math.cos(theta)) + (x * Math.sin(theta))
  return [x_p, y_p]
end
```

That is obviously a circle, so I use the x coordinate and feed it into the equation of my ellipse to get the y(s).

This works and does what it is supposed to, but the problem is that I am only incrementing theta to find my points, so obviously they are not equidistant around the circumference of the ellipse.  That is what I am after, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

You can find a description of the problem with pictures in this thread:

http://www.bigresource.com/Tracker/Track-flash-DO1WzX6KNq/

Comment: Can you just put a link to the image?

Comment: You are unfortunate in that the arclength integral for the ellipse is unpleasant. The actual way to do what you ask is to numerically find the arc length $L,$ then to place each of $n$ points a distance $L/n$ past the previous point, find the $x$ or $y$ coordinate of the point that is the proper distance away. Given what is involved in doing this, I recommend you get some help from a mathematician near you.  

Comment: Yes Will, that is exactly it.  I realized that if I knew how to do that I could solve this, but I haven't had any luck yet.  Also, I unfortunately do not have any resident mathematicians available to me. =)

Comment: Let C be the value of the complete elliptic integral of the second kind. n is the number of points. First find C then solve complete elliptic integral of the second kind set equal to (c/n)m for m=1 to n/4. (use symmetry to get the other 3/4ths of the points.

I don't know if there is a more painless way. 

Comment: Conformal transformations preserve angles... is there a corresponding class of transformations that preserve distances? If so we could find one that take the unit circle to an ellipse and put the powers of (e^2pi*i)/n in to it... anyone know of such a thing?

Comment: Thanks donovan, you should post that as an answer so I can give you some points =).  Also, thanks to Will for reminding me of the term "Arc Length" which is a good keword to use when searching for this problem.

Comment: Nope... In the Euclidean plane there are three basic  isometries:  reflections, rotations, and translations. Any  isometry of the Euclidean is a  composition of these. Looks like this is one for the calculus!

Comment: Yeah, luckily my calculus is *slightly* less rusty than my geometry given that I work in software and have to deal with motion control quite often.  I will give this a shot, thanks guys!  If anyone feels like just writing it down in more complete matter (read: like I am an idiot) don't hesitate. =)

Comment: Yeah, Ed, assuming you will not be that comfortable with general elliptic integrals, the sensible parametrization is $ x = A \cos \theta, \; \; y = B \sin \theta $ for positive constants $A$ and $B.$ Integrals for arc length using such a parametrization are a topic for second-year calculus, often called multivariabvle calculus or vector calculus. But you also need, for some fixed $ \theta_0,$ to numerically solve for the $\theta_1$ such that the arc-length integral from $ \theta_0$ to $\theta_1$ is the required $L/n.$ A competent junior/senior college math major could help quite a bit.

Comment: Too bad you're not interested in "equal area increments", since that'd be one of Kepler's laws of planetary motion and hence all you'd have to do is simulate it!  I think that numerically is the way to go, as in some of the comments above.

Comment: If I remember correctly, Kepler's law states that an orbiting body moves the same area over the same amount of time.  That is pretty much what I have now.

Comment: One thing you might do is this: parametrize the ellipse (probably as Will suggests). Then, the norm of the vector ($\partial x / \partial \theta$, $\partial y / \partial \theta$) gives you the speed with which you are traversing the ellipse at time $\theta$. So, if $s(\theta)$ is this speed, and $\theta_1$ is close to $\theta_2$, an approximation of the distance along the ellipse from $\theta_1$ to $\theta_2$ is given by $(\theta_2 - \theta_1) s(\theta_1)$. A better approximation is
$(\frac{1}{6}s(\theta_1)+\frac{1}{6}s(\theta_2)+\frac{2}{3} s((\theta_2-\theta_1)/2))(\theta_2-\theta_1)$ 

Comment: @biged781: Perhaps I misunderstood the code, but it seems that what you have are equal angle increments. This is not the same as equal time increments in keplerian motion.

Comment: Once you know how big each increment should be (by either doing the integral, or adding up the lengths of a bunch of tiny segments $[\theta_1, \theta_2]$ that make up say $[0, \pi/2]$), you need to know what angle increment, starting at $\theta_1$, will give you arclength $d$. An approximate formula for this is given by $\Delta \theta = d / s(\theta_1)$. Set $\tilde{\theta}_2 = \theta_1 + \Delta \theta$; then you can get an improved estimate by setting $\Delta \theta'$ equal to $2d / (s(\theta_1) + s(\theta_2))$. To make this still more accurate, put together several $d/k$ to get to $d$.

Comment: Another thing you can do is look up "Runge-Kutta method", which may be relevant here.

Comment: 
you can use AGM to speed up elliptic integral evaluation
http://paramanands.wordpress.com/2009/08/12/pi-and-the-agm-evaluating-elliptic-integrals/

Comment: This is basically what Jacobi elliptic functions are about.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi's_elliptic_functions .

In the case of the circle the points are `$(\cos 2 \pi j/n, \sin 2 \pi j /n)$` for integers $j$.  Just substitute the functions $\cn$ and $\sn$ for $\cos$ and $\sin$.

Comment: 
See also http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/283132

Comment: I don't know why everyone assumes that "even spaced along the circumference" refers to the arc length and not to plain old Euclidean distance, as in Agol's answer. biged781, can you, please, clarify what YOU mean by "evenly spaced"? Also, how large is the typical number of points and what are the tolerances?


Comment: As it happens, I wrote some Mathematica code to do this back when I was working on a question at math.SE http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/813020/is-the-area-of-a-pentagon-inscribed-into-an-ellipse-independent-of-starting-poin/813868#813868

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer assumes you are interested in finding $n$ points on an ellipse such that the arc lengths between successive points are equal.

As others mentioned, this problem involves an elliptic integral, which has no elementary expression.  However, many scientific computation libraries are able to compute this function numerically, and you can take advantage of that.  It looks like you're using Python; one possibility here would be the GNU Scientific Library (gsl) for which Python bindings are available.

Say your ellipse is parametrized by $x(t) = a \cos t$, $y(t) = b \sin t$ where $a$ is the semimajor and $b$ the semiminor axis.  Let $e = \sqrt{1-b^2/a^2}$ be the eccentricity.  The arclength from $(x(0), y(0)) = (a,0)$ counterclockwise to $(x(t), y(t))$ is given by $s(t)=a E(t,e)$, where $E(t,e) = \int_0^t \sqrt{1-e^2 \sin^2\theta}d\theta$ is the "incomplete elliptic integral of the second kind".  gsl implements this function as `gsl_sf_ellint_E`.  The total arc length of your ellipse is $S = s(2\pi)$, which you can compute, so you need to find the value $t_k$ such that $s(t_k) = kS/n$, for each $k=0,\dots,n$.  That is, you must solve for $t$ in the equation $s(t) = kS/n$.

But you are able to compute $s(t)$ numerically, and you also know the derivative $s'(t) = a \sqrt{1 - e^2 \sin^2 t}$ thanks to the fundamental theorem of calculus.  Using this, it is a standard procedure to solve the equation iteratively using something like Newton's method.  You could implement it yourself with a bit of reading, or use one of gsl's more sophisticated implementations, e.g. `gsl_root_fdfsolver_steffenson`.

Comment: Thank you!  I am using Ruby in a somewhat constrained environment (a video game engine that is somewhat specific in the way it workd), but I am certain that I can find an equivalent or at least some source code.  I always try to understand what I am doing first, but yeah, I am just a lowly software developer =)

Answer (score 3):

I'll attempt to answer your question by misinterpreting it.

As pointed out in the comments, computing elliptic integrals is not going to be easy. But what if you wanted to find $n$ points arranged around an ellipse which form the vertices of an [equilatera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equilateral)l polygon? Now the answer to the question is given by a real algebraic variety. It's possible that this question may be computationally more tractable.

There are $2n$ variables $(x_i,y_i)$, $i=1,\ldots,n$, and $2n-1$ equations:
$$ \frac{x_i^2}{a^2}+\frac{y_i^2}{b^2}=1,\  i=1,\ldots, n,$$
$$(x_i-x_{i+1})^2+(y_i-y_{i+1})^2=(x_{i+1}-x_{i+2})^2+(y_{i+1}-y_{i+2})^2, i=1,\ldots, n-1,$$
indices taken $(\mod n)$.

Also, for geometric reasons, one expects $n-1$ components to this variety, each of which is a circle. For example, if $n=5$, one would expect two solutions which are oriented in different directions, and two solutions which are star shaped. 
As one moves around the circle, the solution should move around.

Thus, one expects this variety to be a complete intersection defined by quadratic equations. There are methods from algebraic geometry to find solutions to such equations. There are versions of Newton's recursion which may be effective for finding a numerical solution. The dihedral symmetry might further constrain the solutions. Maybe someone could point you to some references if this sort of solution would suffice for your application?

Comment: Thank you very much, I will look more closely at this when I get a chance.  I also saw an allusion to this method on another site.  Thanks again!

Comment: Your use of the nomenclature "regular polygon" is misleading: all you require is that the sides be the same. A true regular polygon is inscribed in the circle, so it can be inscribed in an ellipse only for $n\leq 4.$ 

Comment: The number of components is much larger than $n$ (and closer to $2^n$) unless you impose additional inequalities saying that the points are distinct, or the polygon convex.

Comment: Good point - I suppose these will fold up the n-gon to lower order equilateral polygons. 

Comment: They would correspond to equilateral paths or cycles of size at most $n$, together with a closed walk of length $n$ on this graph (a graph homomorphism from the cycle $C_n$ of length $n$ to the equilateral thing).  Or the same thing modulo rotations/reflections of the homomorphed $C_n$ graph.

Answer (score 1):

The answer, with full Java code is located on StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972331/how-can-i-generate-as-set-of-uniform-points-around-an-ellipse)

### Answered by:

edited Dec 11 '13 at 4:14
John Paul

answered Dec 11 '13 at 3:48
Dave

```
package com.math;

public class CalculatePoints {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    /*
     * 
    dp(t) = sqrt( (r1*sin(t))^2 + (r2*cos(t))^2)
    circ = sum(dp(t), t=0..2*Pi step 0.0001)

    n = 20

    nextPoint = 0
    run = 0.0
    for t=0..2*Pi step 0.0001
        if n*run/circ >= nextPoint then
            set point (r1*cos(t), r2*sin(t))
            nextPoint = nextPoint + 1
        next
        run = run + dp(t)
    next
 */


    double r1 = 20.0;
    double r2 = 10.0;

    double theta = 0.0;
    double twoPi = Math.PI*2.0;
    double deltaTheta = 0.0001;
    double numIntegrals = Math.round(twoPi/deltaTheta);
    double circ=0.0;
    double dpt=0.0;

    /* integrate over the elipse to get the circumference */
    for( int i=0; i < numIntegrals; i++ ) {
        theta += i*deltaTheta;
        dpt = computeDpt( r1, r2, theta);
        circ += dpt;
    }
    System.out.println( "circumference = " + circ );

    int n=20;
    int nextPoint = 0;
    double run = 0.0;
    theta = 0.0;

    for( int i=0; i < numIntegrals; i++ ) {
        theta += deltaTheta;
        double subIntegral = n*run/circ;
        if( (int) subIntegral >= nextPoint ) {
            double x = r1 * Math.cos(theta);
            double y = r2 * Math.sin(theta);
            System.out.println( "x=" + Math.round(x) + ", y=" + Math.round(y));
            nextPoint++;
        }
        run += computeDpt(r1, r2, theta);
    }
}

static double computeDpt( double r1, double r2, double theta ) {
    double dp=0.0;

    double dpt_sin = Math.pow(r1*Math.sin(theta), 2.0);
    double dpt_cos = Math.pow( r2*Math.cos(theta), 2.0);
    dp = Math.sqrt(dpt_sin + dpt_cos);

    return dp;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

an easier method to compute the arclength can be found under 'circumference of an ellipse on wikipedia - a good algebraic approx to the ecliptic integrals' solution envolving functions no more complex than sqrt (). I have been looking at this, it does give the correct circumferance, but I am having issues with making my incremental angle increase from the knowledge of the arc length increment! (this is probably trivial in comparison, any ideas?)

Answer (score 0):

If a practical solution is sought For the problem of getting the euclidean distances equal  then start with the approximate solution from the question,  perhaps fix one point (or don't) and apply an iterative method to improve things. One possibility is a Newton's method for the sum of the squares of the differences of the squared distances.

$\sum(d_i-d_{i-1})^2$ where $d_i=(x_i-x_{i+1})^2+(y_i-y_{i+1})^2$

Perhaps Lagrange Multipliers for the minimization of $\sum d_i$ would yield a solution with points equally spaced and consecutive.